# Load image from a url in ListView android

Tags: java, android, image, listview

I want to load a certain image from a Url into my `ListView`. But I get a `NullPointerException` while loading it. I am fetching data from a Url that returns a JSON response. I have converted the response into `HashMap` which is fine. But further while loading the image i get a `NullPointerException`

Can someone point out a solution for it?
Thanks
Here is my code:-

MainActivity.java

```
 JSONArray jObject = new JSONArray(responseBody);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jObject.length(); i++)
                            {
                                 JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject(i);
                                 String title= menuObject.getString("NewsSourceTitle");
                                 String description= menuObject.getString("Title");
                                 String thumbnail= menuObject.getString("ThumbnailPath");
                                 String newsUrl = menuObject.getString("Url");

                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                                    map.put(NEWSSOURCETITLE, title);
                                    map.put(TITLE, description);
                                    map.put(THUMBNAILPATH, thumbnail);

                                    myNewsList.add(map);


                            }
                            itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(this, myNewsList);
                            newsList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
       public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        public ImageLoader imageLoader;

          public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) 
          {
                activity = a;
                data=d;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                imageLoader=new ImageLoader();
            }

@Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

        @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
            TextView description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description); // artist name

            ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song = data.get(position);

            // Setting all values in listview
            title.setText(song.get("NewsSourceTitle"));
            description.setText(song.get("Title"));


            imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get("ThumbnailPath"), thumb_image);

            return vi;
        }
```

ImageLoader.java

```
 MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String>imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context)
    {
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }
    public ImageLoader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    final int stub_id = com.zevenpooja.attini.R.drawable.myimage;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView thumb_image) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         imageViews.put(thumb_image, url);
         Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
         if(bitmap!=null)
             thumb_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         else
         {
             queuePhoto(url, thumb_image);
             thumb_image.setImageResource(stub_id);
         }

}
    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView thumb_image) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, thumb_image); // ERROR HERE
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));

    }
      private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
        {
            File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

            //from SD cache
            Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
            if(b!=null)
                return b;

            //from web
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
                URI uri = new URI(imageUrl.getProtocol(), imageUrl.getUserInfo(), imageUrl.getHost(), imageUrl.getPort(), imageUrl.getPath(), imageUrl.getQuery(), imageUrl.getRef());
                imageUrl = uri.toURL();
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
               return null;
            }
        }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
            try {
                //decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

                //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
                int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
                int scale=1;
                while(true){
                    if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp/=2;
                    height_tmp/=2;
                    scale*=2;
                }

                //decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
            return null;
        }

        //Task for the queue
        private class PhotoToLoad
        {
            public String url;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
                url=u;
                imageView=i;
            }
        }

        class PhotosLoader implements Runnable 
        {
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
            PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
                this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                a.runOnUiThread(bd);
            }
        }

        boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
            if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
        class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
        {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
            public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
            public void run()
            {
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                if(bitmap!=null)
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                else
                    photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }

        public void clearCache() {
            memoryCache.clear();
            fileCache.clear();
        }
```

LogCat

```
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at Utility.ImageLoader.queuePhoto(ImageLoader.java:59)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at Utility.ImageLoader.DisplayImage(ImageLoader.java:50)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at Utility.LazyAdapter.getView(LazyAdapter.java:73)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-19 08:45:28.132: E/AndroidRuntime(3296):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you give your crash log?

Comment: @Cheerag Have posted the log. kindly look

Comment: wats the value of String constants NEWSSOURCETITLE,TITLE and THUMBNAILPATH in MainActivity.java???

Comment: @Antony there are just some random strings. which later I replace with the values I get from the JSON response

Answer (score 0):

crash log will help more, also take a look on this Volley Lib https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728 maby it will help you to get better performance , also i see that your adapter not have this method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }
```

also try this

```
 if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent,false);
```

Comment: I have used the above method. I cropped the code so that I could simplify the question

Comment: @user3354605 its difficult to help and fine solution when you not provide exact code and crash logs